# show two inputs next to each other in ng-table

Tags: css, angularjs

in a ng-table I ng-repeat over a data-set. in one of the columns I want to show a check-box and a button next to each other. the button should appear when the row is clicked. all functionalities works correct, button appear below the checkbox. how should I do that?

```
<td class="col-md-2">
  <div class="squared">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="{{user}}" name="check" ng-model="enabled" />
      <label for="{{user}}"></label>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save Changes" ng-click="saveUsers(user)" ng-show="user==selectedUser"/>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: This is more a CSS problem than JS/Angular.  Try removing the btn btn-success classes, and see if it solves it

Comment: Is your `col-md-2` wide enough to include both elements?